# Can not find value with array index of zero

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following method:

```
protected function find($obj, $path){
    for($i = 0, $path = preg_split('/[\[\]\.]/', $path), $len = count($path); $i < $len; $i++){
        if($path[$i]){
            $item = ctype_digit($path[$i]) ? (int)$path[$i] : $path[$i];
            if(is_object($obj)){
                $obj = $obj->$item;
            }else{
                $obj = $obj[$item];
            }
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

I am able to pass an object and a string to it, and it usually finds it. I have come across a case where it doesn't work.

```
$data->name = [
    [
        'first' => 'Fred',
        'last'  => 'Hanks'
    ],
    [
        'first' => 'Tim',
        'last'  => 'Duncan'
    ]
];

$obj->find($data, 'name[0].first');
$obj->find($data, 'name[1].first');
```

When doing this, for some reason the first find does not work, yet the second one does.

The first `find()` gives me this error:

> Undefined index: first

But the second `find()` gives me `Tim`. Why is the second find working while the first one is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"0"` is considered `false` when asked `if( $path[$i])`.

It seems like that `if` statement is to remove empty matches (such as the one between `]` and `.`). In this case, use `if( $path[$i] == "") continue;` to more explicitly skip empty string values.

Comment: Ahh... Never thought of that! That was the exact case!